# using a static ip address when accessing internet through wireless (wifi)

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, web-services, networking

I have got a static ip address for lease from my ISP. So the requests for that ip address is forwarded to the modem in my house. from here it is connected to other devices through wifi. On one o the devices my server is running in jboss on port 8080. But all the devices have the same ip address. How can I forward the requests to that particular machine.

Comment: Should probably be on SuperUser

Comment: Do you have NAT on your router? Or port forwarding?

Comment: @DaveRook : I have NAT. But am not sure of port forwarding. I have something called port mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your internal network devices will not all have the same internal IP, otherwise they wouldn't work. What I assume you mean is that they all have the same external WAN ip.

In this case you will need to forward the port in your router settings to the IP of the device running your server.

For example,
WAN ip 12.34.56.78
LAN,
Device 1  192.168.1.1
Device 2  192.168.1.2
Server    192.168.1.3

So you'll want to forward all your port 8080 requests through to the 192.168.1.3 ip on your network.

You can find a short guide on how to forward ports here, http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router

Comment: I have read Link. I don't have port fowarding on my router. I have something called port mapping. It contains Group Name, Grouped Interfaces and Available Interfaces.

Comment: I would make a guess that 'Group name' would be what you call it. 'Grouped interfaces' would be your ports, and then 'Available interfaces' would be where you forward to. Have a google for your router model to see if you can turn up some instructions.

Comment: Finally got it. It is there in the NAT section. But still the request does not get forwarded to the server. What can be the reasons for this? I am able to access internet from the server. I am able to ping the server from another device. But the request on port 8080 is not getting forwarded to the server. My request url is of the form - http://123.123.234.543:8080/appname. Where 123.123.234.543 is a public example (just suppose). I have forwarded the requests on port 8080 to 192.168.1.7 (server). But since it is http, should I also forward requests on port 80?

Comment: If you are looking to serve HTTP requests then yes, I would also forward port 80. Also check the server's firewall and/or iptables to ensure that 8080 isn't blocked on the server.