# Port Forwarding not working in DSL Router

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, webserver

I am using BSNL BroadBand connection and a DSL Router is provided that can act as a Default Gateway to many wireless devices. One such device is my server. I have bought a static ip on lease. So that all the traffic on the to that ip directed to the Router.
 But to forward the request from the router to the my server (which connected using wifi) requires port forwarding (got help from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/454373/using-a-static-ip-address-when-accessing-internet-through-wireless-wifi)). Port forwarding for BSNL DSL Router can be done by going to the `VIRTUAL SERVER` section of the `NAT` section. There I have forwarded all the requests on port 8080 (my JBOSS uses port 8080) to the server, which has an internal ip address `192.168.1.7`.
I am able to connect to internet from the server `(192.168.1.7`), all the devices connected to the Router via wifi are able to ping each other. But traffic on port 8080 is not being directed to the server.
 What can be the possible reasons for this?

**NOTE**
I am able to access the server when my request url is `http://192.168.1.7:8080/myapp`. But When my url is `http://118.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/myapp`. I am not able to access it. 118.xxx.xxx.xxx is the public ip of the router.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It won't work from inside your LAN. It will only work from the rest of the Internet. Here's why:

1. You try to reach your public IP address from a LAN machine.
2. The machine sees that the address is outside the LAN and sends the packet to the router.
3. The router NATs the destination to the LAN machine, but the source address is unmodified (still the LAN machine that originated the request).
4. Your server receives the request and sends a response to the source of the connection (still the LAN machine).
5. The LAN machine receives a response from the server, but it was expecting a response from the router (since it connected *to* the public IP address, it must get a response *from* the public IP address, not the server's LAN address). Since the reply has the wrong source address, it is not accepted. Oops.

Port forwarding (rewriting the destination address) only works from the outside to the inside, not from the inside to the inside. For that, you need hairpin NAT which rewrites the destination address in addition to the source.

Comment: This is what I was trying to say but couldn't got together correctly :) A great explanation.

Comment: @David Schwartz : it works! I tried it from a different network. thanks:) . In the previous scenario is the connection terminated during tcp handshake itself? one more doubt - in point 3 you said, "The router NATs the destination to the LAN machine, but the source address is unmodified (still the LAN machine that originated the request)." When the packet has reached the router, isn't it the routers responsibility to change the source address at layer three to the public ip address (since this is the function of NAT)?

Comment: @Ashwin: 1) The TCP handshake will never complete because the source machine will never receive the reply it is expecting. 2) Port forwarding doesn't involve changing the source address, just the destination. When you port forward to a server, the server still sees the unmodified origin IP address for the connections forwarded to it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : I think I am still confused.  I am trying to access 74.125.236.165 (public ip of google) from one of the devices (forget the server). In this device, during layer 3 encapsulation, the source ip is 192.168.1.5. This is forwarded to the router (which is the default gateway). The router has to hide this private source address. So it functions as a NAT. Doesn't it change this source ip to the public ip of the router? (hiding many private ip's behind on single public ip)

Comment: @Ashwin: Yes, of course. But we were talking about port forwarding (inside destination), not masquerading (outside destination). Masquerading changes the source but not the destination. Port forwarding changes the destination and not the source.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : "Port forwarding (rewriting the destination address) only works from the outside to the inside, not from the inside to the inside" - can u explain this part in the above scenario?

Comment: @Ashwin: For machines from the outside, the server's route to the source IP address already takes the packet back to the router, so the router has an opportunity to NAT the replies. This is not so for machines on the inside. The server's route to inside machines doesn't go through the router, so there's no opportunity for the router to NAT the replies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OKay. So you're on a lan laptop and you want to, for example, SSH to a server you have on your LAN as well. So you try to SSH to your forwarded port saaayy 14522 for 192.168.1.154:22 (port number only being cosmetically named to avoid being the standard port) SO! you hit your public IP (outside interface of the router) on port 14522. Shouldn't it, coming from internal get NATd to a public IP with a source port of whatever, then the get hit on the outside interface at port 14522, forward that packet to the internal IP, and then the interal IP respond back to the public IP on the

Comment: source port. The router gets its response (on another generated port sourced from the server but destined for one more than the source port from the laptops outgoing connection) and then forwards the traffic to the laptop when it gets the response. Then the connection just goes on like normal? Or an I misunderstanding part of how NAT works?

Comment: @PsychoData What you're missing is that the server will send the reply packet (with a private source IP address, since that's all it has) *directly* to the destination, since it's local. That gives the router no opportunity to change the source address to the public IP address. The router would need to rewrite the source IP address (of the packets going to the server) from the source's local IP address to the router's own IP address, which is a form of dual NAT, not mere port forwarding.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but woudnt it do that and be responding to its own public IP?

Comment: @PsychoData The server has no idea what its public IP is. It only has a private IP address assigned to it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz right, but wouldn't the request going to the outside interface get NATd and then have a public IP? and then the server (private address though it has) responds to that public IP generated by NAT. This way wouldn't neither know that it was talking to a computer on the same network, but rather to that public IP address from the NAT?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this because I seem to be doing this exact thing while I'm at my house. But it's working. I'm connecting to a dyndns domain which sends me back to my public IP address and then I connect to my server through the DynDNS domain, which then, I assume, connects back to my same public IP address where my laptop is. Eg. on my laptop I SSH to Psycho@psychodata.no-ip.org:14522 which updates through an update client on the server to my home internet's public IP. Works flawlessly. Isn't this the same thing just with an extra step?

Comment: @PsychoData Yes. Which means your router supports dual NAT, not just port forwarding. If you look at the connections on the server, you'll see the *source* IP address has been changed to the router's IP address.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I dont understand. I cant find anything about "dual NAT" anywhere. I can find stuff about "double" NAT or NAT behind NAT, but not "Dual" Yes, as you said, I see the are from the routers public IP address. But this just seems like my router is working like I would expect ad his isnt. PS. I have a linksys WRT54G plain firmware.

Comment: It just seems weird that the router doesn't nat to the public IP on the way out for the request, and NAT the response coming back, and just forward the ports when something hits on the forwarded ports. 

So, SSH to dyndns.address.com:14522, request goes out, gets NATed to public IP, hits router's outer interface on forwarded port, gets forwarded to server, response from server gets NATed, response hits source port from request, source port response goes to the request-er. Connection works as expected?

Comment: @PsychoData Port forwarding does not involve rewriting the source IP address of connections. If your router is rewriting the source IP address of connections *and* the destination address, then it's doing dual NAT, NAT both before and after routing.

Comment: I'm saying that shouldn't the router NAT on the way out before it tries any port forwarding? NAT to a public IP, then hit the routers outside interface on the port and get forwarded, same thing on the way back, but with the standard generated source port reply of course

Comment: @PsychoData One can certainly argue that it should, but many routers don't support dual NAT, nor will they NAT connections that both originate and terminate on the LAN side.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Where can I read more about NAT vs dual NAT? I'm just confused because I can't find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: @PsychoData [RFC 5382](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5382#section-7.2) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of routers do not allow connections they had forwarded from the local network to its WAN port to traverse back into the LAN (NAT loopback or hairpin). The WAN IP is then inaccessible from inside and you would have to use different addresses to contact the router or the machines to which ports have been forwarded, in your case 192.168.1.7. You can test the port forward from outside. With a web server, the easiest way to do this would probably be to use a proxy such as http://hidemyass.com.

If you want to access the server through a domain name, you will run into the same problem. The DNS servers will direct you towards the public IP address. By editing the hosts files on local machines, you can have them point to the local IP of the server instead, and you would be able to use the same address everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you are able to access 8080 directly (using your 192.168 IP)
2. then in your router, forward 8080 to your jboss server 8080, sometimes router itself might be listening on 8080, in such a case, change your port no

Comment: I am directly able to access 8080 using 192.168.1.7 (my server's ip).

Answer (score 1):

Routers bought from BSNL mostly internally disabled the Port Forwarding facilities. That is , even though you able to see the port forwarding pages and able to set it, the internal lock will block port.

Buy a third party router such as netgear , linksys .. so you can use port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

2)

It's probably because your router doesn't support NAT lookup. You won't be able to access internal computers using your external IP while in the LAN, but the external IP will work to the rest of the world.

If you want to test a website through external IP, then you can use a proxy. I like Anonymouse, but you can choose from thousands of them at proxy.org.

See Is NAT Loopback on my router a security problem? for some debate on whether [NAT lookup is safe or not.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/is-nat-loopback-on-my-router-a-security-problem)

Answer (score 0):

There could be some firewall issues. Some DSL routers may have a firewall in it. Despite port forwarding, sometimes you need to create a rule or completely disable that internal firewall.

Also check the server's firewall. Srin's 1st recommendation points to this, too.

Comment: see my comment for Srin's first answer.

Comment: This is related to routing then. You can't NAT the `118.x.x.x traffic` from the lan interface. `http://118.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/myapp` traffic have to arrive from wan interface of the router in order to be NATed and forwarded to your server. Have you tested your server from outside?