# Non-authoritative answer? Can't connect to my website?

Tags: dns, ftp, connection

Just recently I noticed I couldn't FTP to my site. Then I tried to just go to my site. It didn't work. I decided to wait a day to see if the problem fixed itself. So the next day at school tried going to it on my phone, and it worked. When I got home, it didn't. I think it may be a problem with my DNS. I did nslookup and it said this:

```
> chattle.tk
Server:  www.asusnetwork.net
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:  chattle.tk
Address:  31.170.167.58
```

The thing is, its worked before.  It just randomly stopped, and i didn't install any new firewalls or proxy's or anything.

Comment: Did you try a DNS lookup at school to see if it was *different* from at home?

Comment: Was your phone on the school's wifi?

Comment: No, I was just using data.

Comment: Oh, and I contacted my web host, and he said he could connect to it from where he was.

Comment: Non-authoritative answer just means the DNS server that returned the answer isn't authoritative for the domain, which in your case looks like your local gateway/router (192.168.1.1) - this is normal. The registered nameservers for your domain (ns1.freehostingnoads.net) do return an authoritative answer, which has the same IP as above. So unless you are getting a different answer in different places then it's not a DNS problem (also if you can view the site in a browser but not FTP then it's not DNS for certain). Possibly some firewall setting that blocks FTP?

Comment: I can't view my site in a browser.

Comment: @TravisNabbefeld Then it's probably an issue with your local network or your PC. Did you try with other devices connected to your local network?

Comment: Yes, I did.  It also didn't work from there.

Comment: Actually, on Ubuntu, there has been a lot of problems with this.  Disabling dnsmasq fixes the problem, so it is a dnsmasq + non-authoritative answer problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ATT&T blocking the ip's of the servers.  Not much I can do about that:(

Answer (score 0):

Try running a DNS trace from the two different locations and compare the results. Maybe there's a misconfigured DNS somewhere.

```
dig chattle.tk +trace
```

If it fails from your university, try using Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8) to make sure your SOA is working fine at that time.

```
$ dig chattle.tk +trace @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> chattle.tk +trace @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
.           20377   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           20377   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) in 199 ms

tk.         172800  IN  NS  a.ns.tk.
tk.         172800  IN  NS  b.ns.tk.
tk.         172800  IN  NS  c.ns.tk.
tk.         172800  IN  NS  d.ns.tk.
;; Received 271 bytes from 193.0.14.129#53(193.0.14.129) in 114 ms

chattle.tk.     300 IN  NS  ns2.freehostingnoads.net.
chattle.tk.     300 IN  NS  ns1.freehostingnoads.net.
;; Received 84 bytes from 194.0.40.1#53(194.0.40.1) in 51 ms

chattle.tk.     86400   IN  A   31.170.167.58
chattle.tk.     86400   IN  NS  ns1.freehostingnoads.net.
chattle.tk.     86400   IN  NS  ns2.freehostingnoads.net.
chattle.tk.     86400   IN  NS  ns3.freehostingnoads.net.
chattle.tk.     86400   IN  NS  ns4.freehostingnoads.net.
;; Received 200 bytes from 64.191.115.234#53(64.191.115.234) in 119 ms
```

Comment: I tried using 8.8.8.8 as my DNS and it still didn't work.

Comment: please provide the output for:
`dig chattle.tk +trace` and `dig chattle.tk +trace @8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding only works from the outside to the inside. You are trying to connect from the inside to the inside using a destination IP address that can only work with port forwarding. These two requirements are contradictory.

Unless you're using loopback NAT (sometimes called hairpin NAT, a form of dual NAT), you cannot access a server using its public IP address from the same private network that the server is on. The router has no opportunity to NAT the return packets, which causes them to have the wrong source address when they are received.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/454471/94136) for a walkthrough of how it fails.

Comment: I'm not on the same network as the server.

Comment: And it doesn't work from any machine on your network?